# Creating DjVu files similar to those Archive.org used to make

Tags: djvu

Archive.org unfortunately no longer generates DjVu files, but how did they generate them when they did? How can I generate my own DjVu files, replicating the settings they use:

```
  FORM:DJVU [81493] 
    INFO [10]         DjVu 1835x2927, v25, 300 dpi, gamma=2.2
    CIDa [36] 
    Sjbz [13595]      JB2 bilevel data
    FG44 [1652]       IW4 data #1, 100 slices, v1.2 (color), 153x244
    BG44 [15684]      IW4 data #1, 74 slices, v1.2 (color), 612x976
    BG44 [15946]      IW4 data #2, 10 slices
    BG44 [10783]      IW4 data #3, 4 slices
    BG44 [23422]      IW4 data #4, 9 slices
    TXTz [287]        Hidden text (text, etc.)
```

(I know they use ABBYFineReader, but I'm not interested in OCRing; so, I'm not interested in making DjVus with the TXTz layer.)